# How to optimize this heavy MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I need to optimize a MySQL query which takes a lot of time to load.

Here it is :

```
SELECT 
p.id, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.last_answer_date) AS last_answer_date_timestamp, 
p.sender_id,
p.recipient_id,
p.is_read_sender,
p.last_answer_user_id,
p.is_read_recipient,
(SELECT m.read FROM pm_message m WHERE m.conv_id = p.id AND m.user_id != $user_id ORDER BY m.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS read_status,
(SELECT m.content FROM pm_message m WHERE m.conv_id = p.id ORDER BY m.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_message,
(SELECT u.username FROM user u WHERE (u.id = p.sender_id OR u.id = p.recipient_id) AND u.id != $user_id LIMIT 1) AS from_username,
(SELECT u.id FROM user u WHERE (u.id = p.sender_id OR u.id = p.recipient_id) AND u.id != $user_id LIMIT 1) AS from_userid,
(SELECT ui.gender FROM user_info ui WHERE (ui.user_id = p.sender_id OR ui.user_id = p.recipient_id) AND ui.user_id != $user_id LIMIT 1) AS from_gender,
(SELECT ph.thumb_url FROM photo ph, user_info ui WHERE ui.main_photo = ph.id AND (ph.user_id = p.sender_id OR ph.user_id = p.recipient_id) AND ph.user_id != $user_id LIMIT 1) AS from_thumb_url 
FROM pm_conv p
WHERE p.sender_id = $user_id OR p.recipient_id = $user_id
ORDER BY p.last_answer_date DESC LIMIT 25;
```

This query gets me the result I want but it's really slow... And I think that the nested selects is the reason why this query is so slow.

Here are the tables structures for this query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumb_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `comments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `text` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pm_conv` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_answer_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nb_messages` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_read_sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_read_recipient` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_answer_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `recipient_id` (`recipient_id`),
  KEY `sender_id` (`sender_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pm_message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `conv_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `conv_id` (`conv_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `encrypt_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `register_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned_reason` text,
  `first_step_form` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valid_snapchat` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `introduced_forum` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_social_featuring` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate_app_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_activity_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_info` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` text,
  `main_photo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitter_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `instagram_link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_pref_forum` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_pref_pm` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_pref_snapchat_request` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browse_invisibly` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `main_photo` (`main_photo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Can someone help me to optimize this heavy query?

Thanks!

Comment: So what does EXPLAIN have to say?

Comment: Here is what EXPLAIN tells me : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ht6WX.png

Comment: OK. Get the MySQL Workbench and use that for your explain because it gives a graphic interpretation of the execution plan that is much easier to understand and much easier to test solutions with. http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/. Then you can see what happens as you a) remove each sub-query one at a time and measure the impact of each. b) try different query constructions.

Comment: Remove the nested selects one by one to determine which ones are causing your performance problem.  Then focus on those.

Answer (score 0):

you can see in the explain plan some tables are being accessed by inefficient indexes. try to calculate statistics on all the tables to see if it changes something (using analyze table).

Answer (score 0):

You can join `user` table in order to get username and id at once instead of having two subqueries, probably you can do the same with `pm_message`, but it's a little trickier since subqueries have different conditions.
I would also combine `user` and `user_info` tables into, as I can see they have one-to-one relation, so it doesn't makes sense to store this data in different tables. This would allow you to get rid off 4th subquery and simplify the 5th one.
In some cases it is better to perform several queries instead of one with subqueries.